# How to use OAuth2 with Django's session to authenticate users

Tags: django, oauth-2.0

I'm building an app with React and Django, and I'm mainly using Django to respond with JSON to AJAX requests, after processing some data. I'd like to also use it to authenticate users with a variety of social media strategies.

I went through the Google+ OAuth2 guides and have got to the stage where I am getting access tokens and all the other relevant information.

But I'm not sure how to make this work with Django's session to authenticate users.

Comment: you will be needed [django-oauth-toolkit](https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rest-framework/getting_started.html#step-1-minimal-setup) for authentication using OAuth2 in Django rest framework. Have you tried it?

Comment: @Satendra Thanks I'll look into that